# Android - Facial Expression detection from Image using ML Kit Library

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

Currently I'm working on an app for Android. We want to detect features of a face expression. This feature should be detect the face and facial expression from image.
Accuracy should be fine but don’t need it’s perfect. We need expression detection feature work speedy and smooth.

I have tried **ML kit** Library for Detect Face and It’s Working fine, but this library provide only Single expression “**Smile**”, We need result in different different expression like “**Sad**”, “**Surprise**”, “**Angry**”, “**Neutral**” and “**Happiness**”.

I googled a lot and I found many interesting things. There is also a face detection in the Android API. But the returned only single Face Expression **(https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/tree/master/vision/final)** only contains the position of the eyes. And face landmarks So friends have you any reference or suggestion? For what library there are good documentations, tutorials?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! We will prioritize this facial expression detection. Currently I don't have a good solution however maybe you can try analyze it based on face contour API in ML Kit or facemesh in mediapipe?